# Microsoft Graph filter out non-empty list?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-people

Is there a way to get all the `people` with non-empty `phones` lists in a Microsoft Graph call? I've tried

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$filter=length(phones) gt 0
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$filter=phones/count gt 0
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$filter=phones/any(p:p ne 'notanumber')
```

but they all give "Invalid filter clause" (on beta too). Do I just have to set top=zillions and filter client-side?

---

Resources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-people?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
- https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html

Comment: There is no support for filtering this property yet however you can voice your interest in such feature by creating a feature request in [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests).For now you can filter it on your side.

Comment: Moving this to answer :)-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for filtering this property as of now however you can voice your interest in such feature by creating a feature request in [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum.](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) For now you can filter it on your side.

Comment: is it still the case currently ?